# php array in array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-push

I have the folowing code:

```
foreach($itz as $vz) { 
$muAt_val = $browser->getFieldByName($vz);
array_push_assoc($mAtArray, $vz, $mAt_val);              
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[mAt[1701]] => Array ( [0] => 9378 [1] => 9379 )
```

But I would like to have it:

```
[mAt[1701]] => 9378 [mAt[1701]] => 9379
```

How can I do this?

//update
A duplicate index of an array is not possible, i'm using an array for saving an form

```
 $browser->post($url, $parameters); // $parameters = the array
```

When I save the form by hand I get a post(firebug) with:

```
 mAt[1701] = 9378 
 mAt[1701] = 9379
```

This is not possible with an array, how can I make this work?

Thanks,

Comment: The expected output is unclear. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Your third code block isn't a valid array structure. If you just want it to print out in that format, it should be easy to do that.

Comment: I use the Simpletest browser to fill a form and save it. the form has multiselect which is mAt. The multiselect has all the same name "1701"  but different value's "9379 & 9378". When saving the form I use 

    $browser->post('url.html', $array);

I'm a bit stuck now on how to format the multiselect array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use push, use

```
foreach($itz as $vz) { 
   $muAt_val = $browser->getFieldByName($vz);
   $mAtArray[$vz]= $mAt_val;              
}
```

Comment: function array_push_assoc does this, custom function.